# how do i set up iis to have a website and multiple services using the same domain?

Tags: iis

I am using Windows Server 2012R2 and want to have urls like the following for my web site and for services.

Something like

www.myname.com, www.myname.com/service1 and www.myname.com/service2

Is this possible and advisable?

I have tried putting the services and websites into different directories, 
mysite, service1, service2

I am happy to call the service as www.myname.com/service1  for example, but I would need the www.myname.com to redirect to www.myname.com/mysite

Is this the right set up to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, name your folders accordingly and have the yoursite.com/foldername left as default, however for customization you can use 302/301 redirects in order to achieve your intended result. Yoursite.com/sales can redirect to say, sales.yoursite.com or yoursite.com/service3. You may need to enable http redirection in the server manager first. It’s under common http features.

Comment: I ran into issues with the web.inheritance.  
The answer seemed to be a combination of putting enableConfigurationOverride="false" in the application pool configuration inside applicationHost.config and I also used <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">  in the parent web.config